# Reading documents does not work with new PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, api, build, documents

can anyone help me with an issue I am having with PhoneGap. I built an app where it used to work fine on build 3.7.0 (default). Code that would read folder contents, etc would work fine. Now I tried compiling on the new default ver of 5.2.0 and this code does not work. Reading folders/files and writing folders/files does not work anymore. So I went to phonegap and uploaded a new version of my project with config.xml pointing to old ver of 3.7.0 and it does not even compile anymore on phonegap build.

Sample of the code that no longer works on the new PhoneGap Build (but used to work fine on 3.7.0):

```
var docPath;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);  

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onFail);
}

function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    docPath = fileSystem.root;
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Documents", { create: true, exclusive: true }, getDirSuccess, onFail);
}

function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(dirEntry));
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess, onFail);
}

function readerSuccess(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        alert(entries[i].name);
    }
}
```

Parts of my Config.xml file:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="ant" />

<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-flashlight" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-legacy-whitelist" source="npm" />

<icon src="icon.png"/>

<!-- for iOS -->
<feature name="Flashlight">
  <param name="ios-package" value="Flashlight" />
</feature>

<!-- for Android -->
<feature name="Flashlight">
  <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.Flashlight" />
</feature>

<!-- for WP8 -->
<feature name="Flashlight">
  <param name="wp-package" value="Flashlight" />
</feature>
</widget>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing all of the NPM plugins from cordova and putting the phonegap version on the top of my config.xml, and I commented out

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

and all of the "feature" parameters...I was able to upload to PhoneGap Build and compile using 3.7.0. However, reading document content is not working at this time.

Comment: Do you want to move to Cordova 5.x? Your issue has a solution.

Comment: Sure, I am willing to try this. Will this work on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 0):

@Yura,
in as many days as it took for your response, the Cordova team changed things again. This is one of the reasons I suggest people use version with their compiler and plugins. Otherwise, yous code works at the whims of the Cordova team.

The latest change makes the period (.) in the plugin name of the plugin USABLE. Up until a few days ago, you had to use the new dash (-). Which cause problems, because the names that had periods (.) were not officially deprecated. So, in the time since your original post they created a patch to fix this one issue.

In any case, you 've got a long way to go with lots to do.

1. Move to <s>*source=npm*</s> new names with dashes.  Not required.
2. You have all the core Cordova plugins. Remove those you don't need.
3. `<feature (...)>` does not apply to *Phonegap Build*
4. Implement `whitelist`. Required for

   - Cordova 4.x, 5.x or better (required for Google's Play)
   - Apple's iTunes

Here are the documents you need.

1. & 2. [Core Plugins Setup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md)

here is a quick example of the new system:

`<gap:plugin name=cordova-plugin-device         source=npm version=1.0.1 />`

3. From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) –
   [#12 reads](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#012):

> Aside from the debug-server feature, the feature tag is essentially deprecated on PhoneGap Build since PhoneGap APIs were pluginized.

4. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

On this, I am not putting any examples here, because the system will likely change within 6 months. It has issues.

One last thing, you missed the SO label `phonegap-build`, which is likely why it took so long to get this answer.

Let me know how it goes. Best of Luck

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try.

Comment: @Yura, I was tired last night. So I just saw I made a mistake. I meant to say "you need to the new npm name (with dashes)" You are required to use *source=npm* now; the other repository is dead. I have corrected the original.